# How to split string after having certain characters(vb.net)

Tags: string, vb.net, label

I am working on project.It takes a string and display it in a label.
But if the character are more.it goes on and not splitting.I want the string to split and move to next line when the characters are more.
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kww5.jpg)

Comment: There are many websites that have information on this topic, https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet  However, your question is not totally clear.  Do you want to Split the string into chunks (an array), or do you want to insert line feed characters every n characters and thus represent your string 'word wrapped' in your label?

Comment: You haven't specified the UI Platform. Assuming WinForms, check the `AutoEllipsis` property.

Answer (score 0):

When the Label's `AutoSize` property is `true`, it will automatically be resized to display its entire contents. Unfortunately, it does not care about the size limitations of the its immediate parent.

However, if you dock the Label, you should get the desired behavior you're looking for. In the Form's designer, change the `AutoSize` to `false` and change the `Dock` property to `DockStyles.Fill`.

Comment: Probably Anchor Left/Top/Right, based on the design shown there. AutoEllipsis still possibly necessary, otherwise the text is just truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I made it working.I changed the **Auto size** to **true** and change the values of **Maximum size** property of the label,